# Angular 2: Simple input validation

Tags: javascript, validation, angular, angular2-forms

I have a simple input that is meant for a phone number and I'd like to validate that there are only numbers and that the length is 10 digits long.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="client.phone" class="form-input" name="phone" type="phone" [value]="client.phone">
```

What can I do to validate this without using `FormBuilder`?  It seems like `FormBuilder` just complicates things and I'd just like to validate this one input.

Comment: Are you still looking to stay with a template driven form?

Comment: It just seemed simpler and I'm new to Angular2

Comment: I'm looking for the angular way of approaching this

Answer (score 6):

With the built in pattern validator it is very easy:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="client.phone" pattern="[0-9]{10}" class="form-input" name="phone" type="phone" [value]="client.phone">
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example from my Pluralsight course. This first example is using Template-driven forms. It is using a simple pattern to validate the email address:

```
            <div class="form-group"
                [ngClass]="{'has-error': (emailVar.touched || emailVar.dirty) && !emailVar.valid }">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label" 
                    for="emailId">Email</label>

                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input class="form-control" 
                           id="emailId" 
                           type="email" 
                           placeholder="Email (required)" 
                           required
                           pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+"
                           [(ngModel)]="customer.email"
                           name="email"
                           #emailVar="ngModel" />
                    <span class="help-block" *ngIf="(emailVar.touched || emailVar.dirty) && emailVar.errors">
                        <span *ngIf="emailVar.errors.required">
                            Please enter your email address.
                        </span>
                        <span *ngIf="emailVar.errors.pattern">
                            Please enter a valid email address.
                        </span>

                        <!-- This one does not work -->
                        <span *ngIf="emailVar.errors.email">
                            Please enter a valid email address.
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This example uses Reactive Forms for the same thing.

```
    this.customerForm = this.fb.group({
        firstName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
        lastName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],
        email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+')]],
        sendCatalog: true
    });
```

So using a pattern is very much an Angular technique. I was just pointing you to the HTML site because it provided several suggestions for phone number patterns that you could pick from and use in place of the email patterns shown in my examples here.

Let me know if you want the link to the associated github code.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<input type="number" name="phone" max="10">
```

you can use type number and max

Comment: Won't that limit the number to be between 1 and 10? I think the OP wants between 1 and 10 digits.

Answer (score 1):

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

```
<form role="form" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
    <input class="form-input" type="number" [(ngModel)]="client.phone" name="phone" max="10">
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="f.form.invalid">
</form>
```